# Android package manager - install and open APK

Tags: android

I'm using this class to update my application programatically which works perfectly.

```
public static class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask < String, Void, Void > {
 private Context context;
 public void setContext(Context contextf) {
  context = contextf;
 }

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(String...arg0) {
  try {
   URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
   HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   c.setRequestMethod("GET");
   c.setDoOutput(true);
   c.connect();

   String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/Download/";
   File file = new File(PATH);
   file.mkdirs();
   File outputFile = new File(file, "update.apk");
   if (outputFile.exists()) {
    outputFile.delete();
   }
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

   InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int len1 = 0;
   while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
   }
   fos.close();
   is.close();

   String filename = "/mnt/sdcard/Download/update.apk";
   File filez = new File(filename);
   if (filez.exists()) {
    try {
     final String command = "pm install -r " + filez.getAbsolutePath();
     Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
      "su",
      "-c",
      command
     });
     proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }



  } catch (Exception e) {
   //Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
  }
  return null;
 }
}
```

As you can see the class makes use of `"pm install"` command.

What I want to do is to run the updated app as soon as the installation is completed, so the user doesn't stay outside application. Is there any way I can achieve this through package manager or adb?

Comment: I'm assuming you are on a rooted device, right? Because I'm getting "Permission denied" exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String cmd = "am start -n " + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/." + getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName();
...
os.writeBytes("pm install -r " + filename + " && " + cmd);
...
```